# 'Editor does not contain main class' error appears when I run my GUI code to test if it functions correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface

I have a main class in the code but it comes up with the error 'Editor does not contain main class' , I have written the code again in a separate file but it still does not seem to work.
(I am making a game where 2 players roll 2 die and after 5 rounds the player with the highest score wins)
Here is my code below:

```
package game;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    // Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI window = new GUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Create the application.

    public GUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    //Initialise the contents of the frame.
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 589, 402);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel enterName = new JLabel("Player1 enter your name");
        enterName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 32));
        enterName.setBounds(76, 11, 387, 93);
        frame.getContentPane().add(enterName);
        
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        textField.setBounds(86, 99, 381, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton confirmButton = new JButton("Confirm name");
        confirmButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String p1 = " ";
                String p2 = " ";
                int count = 0;
                if (count == 0) {
                    p1 = textField.getText();
                    textField.setText("");
                    System.out.println(p1);
                }
                if (count > 1) {
                    p2 = textField.getText();
                    System.out.println(p2);
                }
                System.out.println(p1 + p2);
                enterName.setText("Player2 enter your name");
                count = count+1;
            }
        });
        confirmButton.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        confirmButton.setBounds(184, 145, 185, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(confirmButton);
        
        JLabel winnerText = new JLabel("");
        winnerText.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 38));
        winnerText.setBounds(76, 191, 468, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(winnerText);
    }
}
```

I ran the code to see if the GUI would appear and function correctly but every time I just got the same error, I have restarted Eclipse multiple times and it did not fix the issue, I have searched for a fix online but have yet to find one that works.

Comment: Use Alt+Shift+X then J (for running the Java build)

Comment: It still comes up with the error, it might have something to do with WindowBuilder as I'm using that to make the Gui

Comment: It works fine for me. Not sure why you get the error. Let me also try using WindowBuilder and see if that causes an error

Comment: Please prove with a screenshot that the code is in a source folder of a Java project without errors and opened in the active editor.